# AngularJS translate with plural and ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I am looking to use the angular translate and trying to provide different messages based on the "count". I have to use ng-bind-html.

My template is:

```
<div ng-bind-html="'DELETE_MESSAGE' | translate: { name: someName }">
</div>
```

The translate should result in:

1. Case where there is 1 item - "Are you sure you want to delete this item from {{someName}}?"
2. Case where there are N items (N > 1) - "Are you sure you want to delete these {{N}} items from {{someName}}?"

How should I change the template and define 'DELETE_MESSAGE'?